# How to insert a full width band of colour at the bottom of a webpage using css

Tags: css

I have a COTS web app that allows me to customise the css by altering a special file for the purpose.

I need to add a banner approx 20px in height at the bottom of the page. When the page scrolls the banner (can be just a solid colour) should remain static.  However, I don't want the banner to appear over the top of any other content, so the body(?) Should be moved up by 20px.

I have managed to add the banner to the top by altering a couple of existing elements. But to put this at the bottom doesn't work - either because the layout doesn't allow it (DOM?), or just because I don't know how yet.

Is it possible to use css to add this banner to the bottom as I'd like?  Any general advice and guidance would be appreciated. Obviously specifics would be difficult without seeing the app and its code.

Comment: can you show us your code as well? please include a [mcve] to the question

Comment: What have you tired? What was the result? How did it fall short? StackOverflow is used "Get answers to practical, detailed questions", not general advice.

Comment: It's difficult to show my code without reproducing the vast amounts provided by the product itself. However, for the top banner that works I have tried to simply move to the bottom. Unfortunately it seems constrained by the header container so it just ends up at the bottom of the header not the page.

Comment: Do you mean at the bottom of the page or at the bottom of the viewport (screen)?

Comment: It would be the bottom of the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can position an element at the bottom of the viewport and fix it there, so it remains even if the page has to be scrolled.

However, if the whole page is longer the very bottom of it will never be shown as it will lie under the fixed element. To get round this you could give the body a bottom margin of the same height so it will clear the fixed element on scroll.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.tall {
  height: 200vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-image: linear-gradient(magenta, cyan);
}

.band {
  position: fixed;
  top: calc(100vh - 20px);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="tall">Lots of content</div>
  <div>END OF PAGE</div>
  <div class="band"></div>
</body>
```